# Printing different values within class in Python

Tags: python, class

I've been trying to get the method to print out the specific attribute within class. Although I've already used _*str*_ for another thing, and for now it returns the location of my method, which is useless to me.

```
class Account():

    def __init__(self,name,value):

        self.name = name
        self.value = value


    
    def __str__(self):
        return f'Account owner: {self.name}\nAccount balance: ${self.value}'

    def owner(self):
        return self.name

    def balance(self):
        return self.balance
```

You get the idea, I wanted it to return the name user passed in Account class.

Comment: What is the output you expect? What is the output you are getting? Please provide the code you use to test your code.

Comment: You have a typo in `balance()`. Should be `return self.value`.

Comment: _I wanted it to return the name_ When you say "it", what exact method are you talking about?  You already have `owner()` that returns the name.  What other method do you want to return the name?

Comment: "...get the method to print out the specific attribute within class" is an inappropriate strategy. Implement a method to return the appropriate value then print it elsewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it like this:

```
class Account():

    def __init__(self,name,value):
        self.name = name
        self.value = value

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Account owner: {self.Owner}\nAccount balance: ${self.Balance}'

    @property  # note here a property to make external access more obvious
    def Owner(self):
        return self.name

    @property  # note here a property to make external access more obvious
    def Balance(self):
        return self.value  # this is the property you need


if __name__ == '__main__':  # a very simple test, common idiom
    acct = Account("TomServo", 100.40)
    print(acct)
```

OUTPUT:

Account owner: TomServo

Account balance: $100.4

Comment: Works just right, thanks!! So the @property kind of attaches element defined below to __str__, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, while it's a good idea to use meaningful attribute names, if 'Balance' more correctly describes what 'value' represents, then the 'Balance' property can just return the more generic term 'value.'  This can be helpful as your programs become more complex and you start using subclasses and inheritance.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that there's nothing wrong with accessing `acct.name` directly. If you later decide to be more "protective" about doing so, you can replace the attribute `name` with a property called `name` without breaking existing code.

Comment: @racoonfused `@property` masks a method in a way so that it's accessible like an attribute - `self.Balance` instead of `self.Balance()`. It has nothing to do with `__str__` directly.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of the following function is wrong.

```
def balance(self):
   return self.balance
```

The `self` will have 2 attributes,

1. name
2. value

The correct defination is

```
def balance(self):
    return self.value
```

Comment: That's true, didn't get to notice it, since I wasn't getting a string in the output, as I mentioned. Cheers though!